# Scan a network folder in Windows Defender (Windows 8.1) via command line?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, network-shares, windows-defender

In Windows 8.1, we can instruct Windows Defender to perform a custom scan, via command line, like this:

```
MpCmdRun -Scan -ScanType 3 -File "D:\My Personal Docs"
```

Can the same be done with network locations (UNC paths), like this?

```
MpCmdRun -Scan -ScanType 3 -File "\\NetworkShare\Shared Office Docs"
```

I don't have access to a Windows 8.1 machine at the moment which is why I'm asking here. Hopefully someone already knows or can try it.

Comment: I just checked it with my network drive--an Ubuntu Server running a Samba share-- and it didn't work: [Image 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aMhB4.png), [Image 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1EHAw.png). It failed with error: [0x80508023](https://www.google.com/search?q=0x80508023).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this myself, sadly it didn't work. I guess you've have to assign driver letters to each one or use IP's.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

There is a `-UNC` switch you can pass if you are doing a signature update, but quoting from [Technet Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/3ad96d31-afba-445e-aa70-bcd47b496d08/using-mpcmdrunexe-for-remote-scan?forum=FCSNext): "On-demanded scan could only scan file/folder on local disk. So you cannot run custom scan for remote server "

The solution suggested is to use [`psexec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to connect to the system hosting the UNC sharename and performing a `MpCmdRun` on that machine with a custom scan pointing to the local path via something like:
`psexec \\NetworkShare -s cmd /c MpCmdRun -Scan -ScanType 3 -File "D:\Shares\Shared Office Docs"`

Of course, this requires the remote machine to also have Windows Defender and the PsExec service available.